# Effect of stop words in sentiment analysis

Tags: natural-language, sentiment-analysis

I'm using Naive Bayes algorithm to classify movie reviews (positive and negative). I tried to eliminate stop words (by a stop words list) before running the algorithm then I realized it led to a worse accuracy than not doing that.

My question is if stop words really have affection in sentiment analysis and we should not eliminate them?

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/205078/latent-semantic-analysis-stop-words-and-link-words